# How do I disable the raycaster click event on an a-entity in Aframe?

Tags: javascript, events, aframe, raycasting, webvr

I want to disable the click on an entity after it's been clicked once by the raycaster. The entity opens up a panel so I don't want it to show more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends whether or not you're using `raycaster="objects: ...;"`. This is usually the recommended approach so your raycaster isn't interacting with every entity in the scene causing a drop in performance.

This can be done many ways, but one of the most common is to use a class selector like `.clickable` and then remove that class upon click. Then remove the event listener if it is no longer needed.

**Cursor Raycaster:**

```
<a-cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable;"></a-cursor>
```

**Component:**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('click-once', {
  init: function () {
    var self = this;
    var scene = self.el.sceneEl;
    var raycaster = scene.querySelector('[cursor]').components.raycaster;

    // Define function to be executed on click.
    var clickHandler = function (e) {

      // Log clicks.
      console.log('clicked');

      // Remove "clickable" class from entity.
      self.el.classList.remove('clickable');

      // Refresh raycaster object list to reflect changes.
      raycaster.refreshObjects();

      // Remove event listener since no longer needed.
      self.el.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);

    };

    // Add event listener for click.
    self.el.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }
});
```

EDIT: This can be simplified even further if `data-xxxx` attributes or components are used as selectors, rather than classes/ids. E.g.: `data-clickable`

By default, A-Frame's `raycaster` automatically refreshes when entities and attributes/components (not classes) are added/removed, so there is no need to use `raycaster.refreshObjects()` in this case. https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/raycaster.html#properties_autorefresh

HTML:

```
<a-entity cursor raycaster="objects: [data-clickable];"></a-entity>
```

JS:

```
self.el.removeAttribute('data-clickable');
```

**Demo of the code in action:** https://codepen.io/dansinni/pen/MGKGZq

EDIT: If you are using `<a-cursor>` rather than `<a-entity cursor="..."`, then you may need to use the following `var raycaster` assignment:

`var raycaster = scene.querySelector('a-cursor').components.raycaster;`

Or, if you are attaching the `raycaster` component explicitly:

`var raycaster = scene.querySelector('[raycaster]').components.raycaster;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using this code and it seems to be mostly working, but I'm getting this error:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshObjects' of undefined

I'm not sure why it sees raycaster as undefined but is still working. Any ideas?

Comment: @schatzkin: I updated my answer to address your issue. See the edit toward the end.

Comment: I've updated my answer and demo to show how data attributes or components can be used rather than classes. This method is superior because there is no need to manually refresh the raycaster object list since A-Frame does it automatically by default when entities, components, and certain attributes (e.g., `data-xxxx`) are added/removed.